# kill process windows using taskkill

Tags: windows, process, kill, taskkill

I have a java script which is running and kills some processes according to the pid.
I run a shell with command of "taskkill /F /pid " adding the pid of the process.
I have a problem that sometimes those processes are not killed. altouth I run the script again.

1) How can I find out why it is not killed ?
2) *** Do you know a stronger program (than taskkill) in order to kill a process ???

10X

Comment: So this works sometimes, but not others?

Comment: Try putting a pause in the script so you can see what error there was, it might be that there is a handle on the file still which needs to be closed first.

Comment: I thought it was the opposite around. Trying to delete a resource that is used by another process is not enabled

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I meant in your script you have have something like `taskkill /f /pid` then you can put `pause` to see if you get process is in use or access denied error.

Comment: ha, OK. But how can I see if "process is in use or access denied error" ? by the return value from the shell run ?

Comment: If the cmd window pauses after executing taskkill (provided that you use `pause` then you might get an error showing in the cmd window like this `ERROR: The process "System Idle Process" with PID 0 could not be terminated.
Reason: This is critical system process. Taskkill cannot end this process.`

Answer (score 0):

There is a very useful tool called wmic that provides powerful process termination mechanisms.

`wmic process where "ProcessId=1234" CALL Terminate`
, 1234 being the pid of the process you want to kill

for more details on how to use wmic see [wmic](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tgp/scsadmins/winadmin/WMIC_Queries.txt)

Comment: If `taskkill /f` won't do it, WMI won't do it either. The process probably hangs around because it still holds on to some handle that cannot yet be closed.